# SELECT SOQL on Custom Objects on Master-Detail Relationship

Tags: soql

I have 2 custom objects

1. addressMaster
2. addressDetail - has foreign key field which is linked with the id field of the master.

Here is SOQL I tried:

```
SELECT Id, Name, sumchans__totalUnits__c, (SELECT sumchans__aaUnits__c,sumchans__lastReportDate__c,sumchans__nnUnits__c,sumchans__addressForeignKey__r  FROM addressDetails) FROM sumchans__addressMaster__c where id='a014600000C7DNlA3N'];
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with any subquery, you have to *use the correct relationship name*. It is quite trivial to find via a script such as:

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.MyObject__c.getChildRelationships())
    if (relation.getSObject() == Child__c.sObjectType)
        system.debug(relation.getRelationshipName());
```

The debug statement should give you exactly the name of the relationship you should use in the join. Likely instead of `sumchans__addressDetail__c`, it is `sumchans__addressDetails__r`. Note that it is plural and ends in `__r`, not `__c`.

Comment: Sorry Adrian, just was confused with the code, wondering would you be able to use my code above as an example an mark the places where changes are required.

Comment: The error message itself tells you *exactly* what you need to fix...

Comment: I have the made some changes to original post. I used the plural name of the child object in the inner soql. Still I get an error.

Comment: I was able to make it work finally

Comment: thanks for highlighting the plural vs. singular detail. made a massive difference